# docker-compose on Ubuntu: how to ignore disabled service dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, dependencies

docker-compose on Ubuntu: how to ignore disabled service dependencies?

```
services:
  db:
    ...

  app_production:
    ...
    profiles: ["app_production"]

  app_debug:
    ...
    profiles: ["app_debug"]

  proxy:
    depends_on:
      app_production:
      app_debug:
```

Run:

```
docker-compose --profile app_production up
```

No issues on Windows.

But on Ubuntu, error:

```
 app_debug is disabled.
```